# Spam boot activities on form inputs

Tags: spam, botattack

Spam boot activities on form inputs.

Please this question is not on how to protect sites against spam boots via google recaptcha, captchas, maths questions etc.

Am wrting to know how spambots operates. I just need to be highlighted on these few points.

Spamboot generally filled all the form fields they encounter.

**My question is since they easily fill all the form.**

1.)Do spambots focus form inputs as they inserts.You know for every insert, the form inputs has to be focused.?

2.)Do spambots inputs data, remove data inputed from a form input fields just like human.?

3.)How do spambots triggers a submit button. Its the same way human does.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a school thesis and not about running your own website.

Comment: Questions has been edited. i will implement it on mysite as well

Comment: Bots read the form with an HTTP `GET`, search for `<input>` tags, generate a corresponding `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then do a [`POST`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) to the site. No graphics involved so no idea of _focus_ or _button_. There isn't much of a need (although the `<button>` name will probably be included in the `POST` data.)